# building visualization_common (ogre) on archlinux

Tags: ros, boost, archlinux, ogre

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Arch) guide I'm trying to get ROS installed on arch linux. I've worked my way to the very last step which frequently gives linker errors related to boost (i.e. my boost libs are 1.5 but I believe ROS is currently expecting 1.4x). For the most part I've been able to get past these by adding rosbuild_link_boost(package system) to all the affect CMakeLists.txt files, but while building ogre in visualization_common this doesn't seem to be the right solution since everything in there is build outside of the ROS environment.

So my question is this:

1. Is it possible to have ROS use the default arch linux [ogre](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/i686/ogre/) install? This would be the easiest solution since it just works.
2. Barring that, what is the proper way to go about linking in the boost system library for ogre?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46897/building-visualization_common-(ogre)-on-archlinux/) by [ryan0270](https://answers.ros.org/users/3480/ryan0270/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-10-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, this probably isn't useful any more, and Groovy is a much better target for Arch.
But I got visualization common building with boost 1.5x with a patch to CMake/Dependencies.cmake :
-set(OGRE_BOOST_COMPONENTS thread date_time)
+set(OGRE_BOOST_COMPONENTS thread system date_time)

Then adding the patch filename to the visualization_common/ogre/Makefile:
-TARBALL_PATCH = hidden_window.patch hidden_window_glx_fix.patch multi_scene_manager.patch
+TARBALL_PATCH = hidden_window.patch hidden_window_glx_fix.patch multi_scene_manager.patch ogre_boost150_system.patch

---

Originally posted by [pallegro](https://answers.ros.org/users/1891/pallegro/) with karma: 36 on 2012-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0